# How can I use the same alertbox multiple times with a different input boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to use the same alertbox for 3 different `input` so I tried changing it into a `class` and `getElementsByClassName` but it doesn't work. What I did when I tried it as class is `<input type="text" class="form-control date notif" value="Blah blah">`  Please help :D

alert:

```js
 var input = document.getElementById('notif');
     var alert = document.getElementById('alert');
    
     notif.addEventListener('focus', function() {
       alert.classList.add('in');
    
       setTimeout(function() {
         alert.classList.remove('in');
       }, 4000);
     });
    
     notif.addEventListener('blur',function (){
       alert.classList.remove('in')
     });
```

```html
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-warning fade">
 <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" style="text-decoration: none">&times;</a>
 Warning: Please don't
</div>

 <div>
     <span>
      <input id="notif" type="text" class="form-control date" value="Blah blah">
     </span>
     <span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control date" value="Pew pew">
     </span>
     <span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Pak kapow">
     </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is `alert` dom?

Comment: Be clear you want to show javascript prompt or alert box created with HTML. I can not find element with id='alert'

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it is not import because it's just an alert box

Comment: you want all of those inputs to use just one alert?

Comment: @L.Herrera Yes can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If it's stupid but it works, it isn't stupid"

-murphy

```
 var input = document.getElementById('notif');
        var alert = document.getElementById('alert');

        notif.addEventListener('focus', function() {
          alert.classList.add('in');

          setTimeout(function() {
            alert.classList.remove('in');
          }, 4000);
        });

        notif.addEventListener('blur',function (){
          alert.classList.remove('in')
        });
var input = document.getElementById('notif2');
            var alert = document.getElementById('alert');

            notif2.addEventListener('focus', function() {
              alert.classList.add('in');

              setTimeout(function() {
                alert.classList.remove('in');
              }, 4000);
            });

            notif2.addEventListener('blur',function (){
              alert.classList.remove('in')
            });
```

and so on

```
 <div>
        <span>
            <input id="notif" type="text" class="form-control date" value="Blah blah">
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="notif2" type="text" class="form-control date" value="Pew pew">
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="notif3" type="text" class="form-control" value="Pak kapow">
        </span>
    </div>
```